# How can I append my select2 to a div box?

Tags: jquery, css, append, jquery-select2

I want to append my `select2` to a div `box`. But then it is not working anymore.

Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r7cop362/165/

```
<select class="select2" >
    <option selected="selected">Kerry</option>
    <option selected="selected">Cork</option>
</select>
<div id="box"></div>


$('.select2').select2();
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#box").append("<select class='select2'><option selected='selected'>Cat</option><option selected='selected'>Dog</option></select>");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a call to `select2()` again after the *append*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#box").append("<select class='select2' ><option   selected='selected'>Cat</option><option selected='selected'>Dog</option> </select>");
  $('.select2').select2();
});
```

[**`UPDATED FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/773sdxaa/)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize select2 plugin after appending the select tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#box").append("<select class='select2' ><option   selected='selected'>Cat</option><option selected='selected'>Dog</option> </select>");
  $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#box").append($('.select2'));
```

or

```
$('.select2').appendTo("#box");
```